# JMeter: how to show 99% instead of 90% in Aggregate Report?

Tags: jmeter

Aggregate Report in JMeter by default shows 90% line latency (is that even latency?). I'm asked to provide 99%. Can't figure out where that value could be changed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are at least 2 possible solutions:**

1. Use this plugin, it generates more percentiles than default one: https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RespTimePercentiles
2. Or modify `StatVisualizer.java` class and `message.properties`, as stated here: http://djangoramone.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/jmeter-hack-2-more-percentiles-for-aggregate-report/